# bash: how to wrap or fold long lines at specified punctuations only?

Tags: bash

I understand `fold` could wrap long lines with a column/width limit, and also an option `-s` to do so only at spaces.

```
fold -w20 -s input_file
```

But is there a way to restrict the line length and also only wrap at specified punctuations, like , . ! ? etc.? This would generate more readable lines.

Comment: Could you give an example? The punctuation characters you mention are, in my experience, always followed by a space, so `fold` will work just fine.

Comment: so the source file may be more than just ASCII codes, like composed characters with full-width punctuations e.g., ，。！？In general, these won't be followed by space.

Comment: what should happen if there is no suitable place to wrap?

Comment: you could try a [par](http://www.nicemice.net/par/) patched for multibyte

Comment: I couldn't use things not standard on the remote dev box.